# Function name is not defined at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function, syntax-error, undefined

I want to make X and O game , So the first function i did it has loop and condition that when i click on any cell(td) in the table and if all cells in the table are empty wrote X in the cell which I clicked it , but I have here 2 problem ,
First one The console wrote (Sample1.html:53 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<') it refers to for loop, so I don't know what is the problem there.
the second problem console wrote also that my function name is not define , although the function name is correct so can anyone help me.

the JS codes is

```
<script >
/*var lastGame;*/
var TR=0;
var table = document.getElementById('tb');
function CheckAllEmpty(idClicked){
for(var x=0, x <  table.rows.length; x++){    
if(!table.rows[x])
{
TR++;    
}
else{} 

}
if(TR==9) 
{
document.getElementById(idClicked).innerHTML="X";    
}
else {}
}

</script>
```

And the HTML :

```
  <table id="tb">

  <tr>
  <td id="td1" onclick="CheckAllEmpty(this.id);"></td>
  <td id="td2"></td>
  <td id="td3"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td id="td4"></td>
  <td id="td5"></td>
  <td id="td6"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td id="td7"></td>
  <td id="td8"></td>
  <td id="td9"></td>

  </tr>    

  </table>
```

Comment: You have a `,` where you need a `;`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be other problems with your code, but your two specific problems should be fixed. Also I don't see why you need to check if every cell is empty, but then again I can't see the rest of your code. Feel free to ask any questions in the comments.

```js
var TR = 0;
var table = document.getElementById('tb');

function CheckAllEmpty(idClicked) {
  for (var x = 0; x < table.rows.length; x++) {
    if (!(table.rows[x].value == "")) {
      TR++;
      console.log(TR);
    }
  }
  if (TR == 3) {
    document.getElementById(idClicked).innerHTML = "X";
  }
}
CheckAllEmpty('td1');
```

```html
<table id="tb">

  <tr>
    <td id="td1" onclick="CheckAllEmpty(this.id)"></td>
    <td id="td2"></td>
    <td id="td3"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="td4"></td>
    <td id="td5"></td>
    <td id="td6"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="td7"></td>
    <td id="td8"></td>
    <td id="td9"></td>

  </tr>

</table>
```